# Pass parameter from one jsp to another

Tags: jsp

Even there are many answers available to this question, still i am not able to find what i am missing. Below is my code, where i am trying to pass irepno parameter from main jsp to another using query parameter. But i am receiving null. Please someone help to findout what is the mistake.

```html
main.jsp
<a href="printcurreport.jsp?irepno=${irepno}">Print Current Report</a>

printcurreport.jsp
String repno = request.getParameter("irepno");
```

```html
<label>IRno:</label><input type="text" name="irepno" id="irepno" class="inp" value="<%=session.getAttribute("irepno")%>" /><br><br>
```

[image]

Comment: format is ?param=value. Thus, use getParameter("param") to access to value of param, i.e. getParameter("repno") will work if ${irepno} is not null.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,if it could help you.

main.jsp

```
 <label>IRno:</label><input type="text" name="irepno" id="irepno" class="inp" value="<%=session.getAttribute("irepno")%>" /> 

 <a href="printcurreport.jsp?irepno=<%=session.getAttribute("irepno")%>">Print Current Report</a>
```

printcurreport.jsp

```
<%
  String irepno=request.getParameter("irepno");
  request.setAttribute("irepno",irepno);

%>
```

Comment: No. Could you please tell me how to proceed

Comment: <label>IRno:</label><input type="text" name="irepno" id="irepno" class="inp" value="${irepno}" scope="request"/><br><br> this is my input parameter in main.jsp

Comment: I am not much clear on session. could you please help me out

Comment: Its simple. I have a text field called irepno in my main jsp. I want to just pass which is present in that field along with 2nd jsp(so that i can get it in 2nd using get parameter) when user click on link (mentioned in above code). since i am not clear on session scope. i dont know how to proceed. so please help

Comment: thanks for ur support. But it should happen without submitting the form.

Comment: user will not fill this. rather during page load it will comeup with some alphanumeric number based on table data. and also href link also present  in main jsp. Please check my edited post, added an image..where u can see print current report href is one of the link given in print icon dropdown and repno present in right side. all in  main jsp

Comment: Could you please confirm/ recheck!!! because i am getting null--> /printcurreport.jsp?irepno=null

Comment: @kavi you said  during page load value will comeup with some alphanumeric number based on table data how you are setting value in that text box?.. in same way you need to do in link

Comment: that text box will be populated dynamically during page load using jquery

Answer (score 0):

Yes to pass the values we have many ways,

from your example it seems you wanna pass values through QueryStrings.

In your code you are making mistake in the parameter, you are not fetching value through correct parameter which you have set in previous page.

```
    - main.jsp

         <a href="printcurreport.jsp?repno=${irepno}">Print Current Report</a>

          // Make sure irepno has some value. 

    - printcurreport.jsp

       <%   out.println(request.getParameter("repno"));  %>

         // In your code you are making  mistake here in the parameter, you are not fetching value through correct parameter which you have set in previous page.
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how the value will be assigned  to ${irepno}

Comment: can you tell me what is "irepno" in your case ? is that some object ? variable ?

Comment: its one of the text field in my main jsp page. like <label>IRno:</label><input type="text" name="irepno" id="irepno" />